# Xamarin Forms - Android Splashscreen are shown also in main application

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I have added a splashscreen to my application adding

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashScreen</item>
```

to the `MainTheme` of my application.

The splashscreen appears correctly at application starts but remains as backgound in all the pages of the application.

How can I avoid this behavior?

[Here](https://ufile.io/y3wm0) a video to better show the behavior.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have at least two themes. One for splash screen and other for rest of your app(You can have other themes for specific pages as well).

In my case I have "splashscreen" for splash screen and "AppTheme" for rest of the app.

Define splash theme as :

```
<style name="splashscreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/Zenon_Welcome_Screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    </style>
```

And  AppTheme as :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- App theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#c62828</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#8e0000</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#8e0000</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>
```

Now in your main activity :

```
[Activity(Label = "AppName", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/splashscreen", MainLauncher = true,
              ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)]
    public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
```

Now in the onCreate method you need to switch the theme like below :

```
        /// <summary>
        ///    On create.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="bundle">Bundle.</param>
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);

            // Name of the MainActivity theme we want to use for the app.
            // Or we can use global::Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloLight / Theme Name.
            base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.AppTheme);

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
        }
```